# How to select one record in sql query in java code?

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot

I am getting error in below query as

```
@Query(value = "SELECT top 1 * from Job where status = 'Success' order by 1 desc")
public Job getLastJob();
```

> Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: top near line 1,

I want to select 1st row which has success status order by id desc

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server (or similar)? `TOP` is a product specific functionality.

Comment: SQL - and if I remember correctly JPQL/HQL too - uses the `LIMIT` term, i.e. `SELECT * FROM ... ORDER BY xxx LIMIT 1` to get only the first record.

Comment: Or mark this query as native query like `@Query(value = "SELECT top 1 * from Job where status = 'Success' order by 1 desc", nativeQuery = true)`